# Can I anonymously self-publish books on Amazon and get paid in Bitcoin?

Tags: litecoin, payment, privacy, tor

I want to publish the book under a pseudonym, or better yet, anonymously! I had been looking into Amazon Kindle Direct Publishing. I’d also like to use an anonymous e-mail address. Would it be possible to get paid in Bitcoin when I publish my book there?

I want to get paid in Bitcoin/Litecoin only (possibly some other cryprocurrencies too, but I really don’t want centralized payments).

If there’s no way to do this, please tell me about any other alternatives for self publishing and/or advertising!

Comment: It certainly seems like amazon could allow you to publish anonymously, if they chose. But *why would they want to?* Suppose that you upload a book that is mostly a plagiarized version of another book, and they find out after a thousand people have bought it. If they know who you are, they can sue you for ripping them off. If you're anonymous, they have no recourse.

Comment: There must be a way for them to see that I am not breaking the law in any way.For example,I give them a copy of my book for free and after someone is going to read and review it,they will publish it just afterwards.Isn't this a good safety measure?

Comment: This probably depends on your local laws.  For instance, in the US, I believe you would have to give Amazon your real name and SSN/TIN so that they could report your income to the IRS.  They could leave your name off the book, and in principle they could pay you in Bitcoin, but you wouldn't be anonymous.